# Why Make keeps creating directory over and over?

Tags: linux, make, makefile

i have a makefile that creates some docs from my source:

```
/home/share/htdocs:
   #installs apache and make sure we have /htdocs...

/home/share/htdocs/doxjs: /home/share/htdocs
   mkdir -p $@
   chgrp users $@
   chmod g+w $@

/home/share/htdocs/dox: /home/share/htdocs
   mkdir -p $@
   chgrp users $@
   chmod g+w $@

.PHONY: dox
dox: /home/share/htdocs/dox /home/share/htdocs/doxjs
    # runs doxygen
    cp -r dox/html/* /home/share/htdocs/dox/
    cp -r doxjs/html/* /home/share/htdocs/doxjs/
```

Those rules should just create and set permission to serve the files from htdocs, build documents, and move them over.

but when i run. it will *always* try to create `/home/share/htdocs/dox`

any ideas why?

even if i use:

```
.PHONY: setup
setup: /home/share/htdocs/dox /home/share/htdocs/doxjs
```

this is what i get:

```
$ sudo rm -fr /home/share/htdocs/dox*
$ sudo make setup
mkdir -p /home/share/htdocs/dox
chgrp users /home/share/htdocs/dox
chmod g+w /home/share/htdocs/dox
mkdir -p /home/share/htdocs/doxjs
chgrp users /home/share/htdocs/doxjs
chmod g+w /home/share/htdocs/doxjs

$ sudo make setup
mkdir -p /home/share/htdocs/dox
chgrp users /home/share/htdocs/dox
chmod g+w /home/share/htdocs/dox

$ sudo make setup
mkdir -p /home/share/htdocs/dox
chgrp users /home/share/htdocs/dox
chmod g+w /home/share/htdocs/dox
```

why? I am assuming I do not see some conflict with modified times. But I can't imagine what.

Answer (score 2):

I mocked up your structure, and used `make -r -d setup`, where `-d` shows debug output, and `-r` ignores builtin rules, so there's less output. The relevant part is

```
Considering target file 'setup'.
 File 'setup' does not exist.
  Considering target file 'htdocs/dox'.
    Considering target file 'htdocs'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file 'htdocs'.
   No need to remake target 'htdocs'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'htdocs/dox'.
   Prerequisite 'htdocs' is newer than target 'htdocs/dox'.
 Must remake target 'htdocs/dox'.
```

So, after descending into `htdocs`, this directory gets a newer access time than `htdocs/dox`, and therefore `make` concludes it needs to be remade.

Solution: Don't use a parent directory as prerequisite.

Actually, the whole setup to create directories and then run make inside them is a bit fishy; whatever you want to achieve, you should be able to achieve it with a static directory structure.

Comment: what exactly does it means by htdocs is newer? it only checked the rule. by that logic every single dependency would be newer if they are checked first, and that's what happens to a dependency by desig

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running `make -d`? According to the man page this provides:

> Debugging  information  in  addition  to normal processing.  The debugging information says which
>   files are being considered for remaking, which file-times are being 
>   compared  and  with  what  results, which   files  actually  need  to 
>   be  remade,  which  implicit  rules  are  considered  and  which  are applied---everything interesting about how make decides what to do.